# Highlight R syntax using knitr and Package Highlight

Tags: r, highlight, knitr

I try to highlight my R code using knit and Highlight pachages with Rstudio, but i have errors when kniting;

There's my code :

```
opts_chunk$set(fig.width=7, fig.height=5)   
opts_knit$set(use.highlight = TRUE)   
opts_knit$set(out.format = "html")
opts_chunk$set(highlight = TRUE)
opts_knit$set(...., highlight=FALSE)
render_html()
```

and when compiling, I have that error

```
Error in library(package = "parser", character.only = TRUE) :
there is no package called 'parser'
```

I use R 3.0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think I have fixed this problem in the development version, and you can install it from:

```
install.packages('knitr', repos = 'http://www.rforge.net/', type = 'source')
```